# Can we change (La)TeX linebreaking character so that Word understands it?

Tags: pdf, conversion, viewers, msword

Sometimes I need to send someone a `.doc` file of something I did using LaTeX. But when I copy+paste the PDF content generated by (La)TeX into Word the linebreaks are understood as paragraph characters (¶). I don't really mind that the `.doc` file is unformatted, but it's rather annoying to fix the text in Word every time, specially because the actual paragraph break is unknown...

Is there a way to replace the linebreaking character TeX uses so that when pasting into Word the text is "properly" pasted?

If the problem is not clear enough compile the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[0-5]
\end{document}
```

You should get
[image: LaTeX PDF output]

Copy the PDF content and Paste to Word (if you have it), it results in:
[image: When pasted into Word...]

There should be only five ¶ beacause there's only five paragraphs...

Comment: Exactly what are you using to copy the text from the PDF (which previewer?)? I'd assume that the copy just knows about lines, not paragraphs (basically verbatim line by line). And that is it is a mishap that word marks all line endings as a new paragraph.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader. But if what you are saying is true, then how come when I save a `.doc` file as PDF and copy/paste the contents are pasted correctly? That is, linebreaks are not understood as paragraphs. Just to be fair, this does not happen only when pasting into word, the same happens with TeXstudio.

Comment: For fairly simple documents, I have found that tools like `pandoc` or `latex2rtf` do a pretty good job of this. They operate on the LaTeX source file directly, so they don't rely on interpreting the PDF output. Sorry, no time to find links right now, but if you search for these names you can find some tips and examples of what they can do.

Comment: @PaulGessler, thank's for the input, that's a good workaround but it would be better if we could copy the contents of PDF properly, no?

Comment: tex does not insert any character at a linebreak it just positions each line by coordinates, so any plain text cut and paste is a feature of the heuristics in your pdf reader not of tex.

Comment: I don't see it as a workaround at all. The source document has much more information than the output PDF's selectable text stream (think of emphasis, bold text, font size changes, etc. that are lost when copying/pasting a selection of text from a PDF). Plus if you are copying multiple pages there are headings/page numbers to deal with and so on.

Comment: @PaulGessler, but I said in the question: I don't really mind the formatting to be lost. This is not a matter of conversion, simply of copying and pasting. :D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, understood. But still, how come when the PDF is generated by Word the Reader cut and paste feature, as you said, copies the content correctly?

Comment: I've had more luck opening LaTeX PDFs directly in word than copy-pasting, but haven't looked at this specifically.  A word macro could do a clever find-replace to replace single (but not double) line breaks with spaces

Comment: Try different PDF viewers. Skim and Preview on the Mac, for example, which use Apple's PDFkit, copy and paste with no trouble; Adobe Reader doesn't.

Comment: Can you just send your correspondent the pdf and make the problem his or hers?

Comment: quote likely adobe reverse engineered the pdf structure written by word so it's "guess" of what is a paragraph break and what is a line is better for word pdf (or perhaps, but i don't think so) word is adding the pdf structure tagging (which marks paragraphs top allow limited reflow etc)

Comment: @AlanMunn, I tried Nitro and Foxit. Nitro does the same as Acrobat, but Foxit translates the line breaks into actual line breaks, searchable (in Word is `^l`) which is way better, with find and replace it's all gone. Skim and the Mac Preview app are not cross-platform, so not very good... But that shows it's definetely viewer related too!

Comment: IMO this is not really a TeX/LaTeX question  as the same  arise also with PDF created with any software including Word it self. To overcome this problem the find-and-replace standard tool of Word does a faitrly good job for few page's documemt. Workflow: (1) manually insert page breaks between true paragraphs (with key Ctrl+Enter), (2) replace paraphaph breaks (`^p`) by spaces, (3) replace page breaks (`^m`) by paragraphs marks (`^p`) (4)  if any  manually fix suprious spaces at hyphen points.  Steps (2) and (3) are easily wrapped In a VBA word macro, linked to a button or keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Jhor, I do think this is a (La)TeX-related question, since it asks how can a (La)TeX-generated document avoid such an issue. In addition, I think the accepted answer does address the problem, in spite of being lualatex-only. Finally, I appreciate you workaround, however, when the last line of a paragraphs is by the same size of the next paragraph first line, it becomes quite hard to distinct the true paragraph break (e.g. second paragraph of the exemple), thus rendering such task very inconvienent, to say the least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to tag the pdf if the reader should recognize units like "paragraphs". Without it it sees only lines.

As an example run the following with lualatex and compare with and without the `activate-all` key.

### Attention!

tagpdf is an experimental package I wrote to investigate such questions. It is not really meant for production documents. It is not complete yet and things are bound to change. So if you use it you use it at your own risk.

```
%! needs lualatex for the best result
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %to get some hyphenation
\prehyphenchar`\^^ad % with luatex improves copying of hyphenated words (if the font has the soft hyphen). 
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,
             activate-all, %deactivate to see the difference
             uncompress
             }
\usepackage{lipsum}%

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
  \tagstructbegin{tag=P}
   \tagmcbegin{tag=P}
    \lipsum[1]
   \tagmcend
  \tagstructend
\tagstructend   
\end{document}
```

### Result of copy and paste without and with activated tagpdf

[image]

Comment: Interesting... Then for multiple paragraphs one would need to tag the beginning and end of each paragraph?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do this - can be quite some work ;-).

Comment: Btw: an alternative to tagging would be to typeset your document with a very large line width. Then every paragraph is on its own line.

Comment: That's a good point... I just want to know one last thing: can we use pdflatex instead of lua? And can you make the example for two paragraphs? I don't really understand if I'm supposed to enclose each paragraph into both `\tagstructure` and `\tagmc` and also if I should repeat the value of ´tag` for every pararagph or use different values... Thank's

Comment: pdflatex is problematic as `\tagmcbegin` and `\tagmcend` must always be on the same (output) page with this engine, see the documentation for info about this. And yes you need the whole code around every paragraph, but you can naturally define shorter command names, E.g `\PAR` `\EPAR`.

Comment: We discussed at TUG2018 about ways to improve the situation of pdflatex but it will need a change in the output routing and it will take some time to get this working.