# copy pdf without line break in TeXstudio

Tags: line-breaking, texstudio

When I copy the pdf document it will automatically copy the "\n" in each line of pdf

Is it possible to avoid this problem?Since "\n" is meaningless in LaTeX.

A similar question see here [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91567/copy-from-pdf-without-line-breaks-at-end-of-each-line)

I use TeXstudio,it's possible to avoid this break line "\n" in it?

Comment: You would have to tag the pdf (and use a viewer that understand this). See e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444308/2388.

Comment: It's too complicated ,so you mean no way to copy pdf without break line?